# raspberry display touch screen configuration

Tags: raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

I have a raspberry pi3 b+ connected via an AWM cable with a 7 inch raspberry display. I have a devuan OS present on the raspberry with which I launch an x server (startx) to then launch software with an interface. I would like my screen to be touch-sensitive. How do I configure it so that it is?

The first problem is that when I do an xinput list, I have no trace of the raspberry display input device.
I do have the framebuffer fb0, and I've seen that it generally corresponds to the screen connected to the raspberry. But I really don't see how I can make my screen touch-sensitive.